# Requring commenter registration on Orchard CMS blog

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, openid, orchardcms, disqus

I'm looking at the Orchard ASP.NET CMS for a blogging platform but I need to have the users register with some service (Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc) before commenting. Is this possible? I've seen the Disqus comment module but I need to keep the comments on my server. Anyone seen something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Orchard Disqus](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Disqus.Comments) module has an option to *synchronize comments with local database*, so it should work for you. That module is one of the best comment-related ones so I'd stick to that, if I were you.

Comment: Thanks, that should work for me. I didn't see that it synchronized back.